# React Native make network call before render

Tags: react-native

I have a component that displays Users in a ListView which needs to make a fetch call before it renders.

**I navigate to this component using:**

```
this.props.navigator.resetTo({ id: 'ListUsers',  getusers: true });
```

In the `ListUsers` component I have `componentWillReceiveProps` so that I can make the fetch call before render.

However the method is never called.

Further from `ListUsers` I can navigate to the `AddUser` component.

From here either a new user is added or the user can Cancel.

If new user is added, I navigate back to the `ListUsers` component using:

```
this.props.navigator.resetTo({ id: 'ListUsers',  getusers: true });
```

At this point `componentWillReceiveProps` is called.

if user cancelled then I navigate back to the `ListUsers` component using:

```
this.props.navigator.pop();
```

Can anyone help to see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perfectly described what the documentation says will happen when using componentWillReceiveProps

From the docs:

> componentWillReceiveProps
>
> Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not
>   called for the initial render.

In your scenario, is there any reason why you can't use componentWillMount to make the fetch call? componentWillMount is called right before the component is rendered, and it is the first point you can call setState.

If the problem is you need to guarantee that render only shows certain data before the fetch is completed, there are some strategies to do that, but the simplest way may be to simply set a flag to false in your state in the constructor (if you are developing using ES6 methodology), and flip it to true after the fetch is complete. An if statement in your render method would round out this strategy.

If you want me to put together a more comprehensive example, I can do so.